# Dictionary Values Are Strings?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to save raw input elements in a dictionary to a variable. This does not seem to be working though because the information is being saved as strings, and I do not know why. Here is a sample of what I am doing:

```
accounts = {}

def accountcreater():
  accountname = raw_input("Account Name: ")
  accountpassword = raw_input("Account Password: ")
  accountUUID = 1
  accountUUID += 1
  accounts[accountname] = {"password":accountpassword,"UUID":accountUUID}

def login():
  loginusername = raw_input("Account Name: ")
  loginpassword = raw_input("Account Password: ")
  for usernames in account:
    if usernames == loginusername:
      accountpassword = accounts[usernames][???]
      accountpassword = accounts[usernames][???]
    else:
      pass
```

That is a very simple example of what the code is like. Now the part where the "[???]" is I have no idea what to put. I tried putting this code:

```
  accountpassword = accounts[usernames][password]
  accountpassword = accounts[usernames][UUID]
```

But that does not seem to work because it says password and UUID are not defined. Yet I seem to be able to just input [usernames] and it will work just fine. I have also tried putting the follow:

```
  accountpassword = accounts[usernames]['password']
  accountpassword = accounts[usernames]['UUID']
```

This raises this error: **String indices must be integers, not str**.
I am not sure why my cod will not work. Please help me! :D Thank You

Comment: Your `login` function has the line `for usernames in account:`. Where is `account` defined? If you meant to type `accounts`, your second approach [works on my machine](http://ideone.com/tbKABD). Please provide code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: ^methinks that was a typo, cuz it worked fine over here also. also generally, since inside of `account` is a bunch of usernames, and you are only iterating over one at a time `username` would make more sense........ just saying :)

Comment: Use print statements to verify each variable holds the kind of value you are expecting. For example, `print(accounts)`, `print(accounts[usernames])`...

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer you accepted for your previous question, you don't want to initialize `accountUID` inside `accountcreator`; you are going to give every user an account UUID of 2.

Comment: If `accountpassword = accounts[usernames]['password']` gives the error you claim, then you are modifying `accounts` in some way you aren't showing, because the code above sets `accounts[username]` to a dictionary, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for using a dictionary is to *avoid* the need to iterate through the accounts. Use the user name typed by the user as the key to access a record in `accounts`, then use the literal string "password" as the key for that record to get the user's password. Then compare that to the password typed by the user.

```
def login():
  loginusername = raw_input("Account Name: ")
  loginpassword = raw_input("Account Password: ")

  # We'll assume that an account exists for the entered login name
  expected_password = accounts[loginusername]['password']

  if expected_password == loginpassword:
      print "Login successful for {0}".format(loginusername)
  else:
      print "Password {0} incorrect for {1}".format(loginpassword, loginusername)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your use of "for" really isn't proper here, as accounts is a Dictionary and not a List.

Since accounts is a dictionary, you want to check to see if the provided username is in accounts.keys(), then check that entry for the correct password.

So, something like this would work:

```
if loginusername in accounts.keys():
     if accounts[loginusername]['password'] == loginpassword:
          return 'success'
else:
     return 'failure'
```

Now, if accounts were a list, then you would need your for loop.  The dict allows you to avoid that.